# C# ASP.net- Receive WebClient Post to server and read values

Tags: c#, asp.net, json

I'm new at ASP.net C# and also to this site...

I need to POST a JSON value to the server... and return back the same JSON string back from the server to the client...

Code Behind Client side: Default.aspx

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var postURL = "http://localhost:16967/WebSite7/Default2.aspx";

      string json = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(new
        {           
            user = "Foo",
            password = "Baz"
        });

    using (var wb = new WebClient())
    {
        var data = new NameValueCollection();
        data["jsonString"] = json;            
        var response = wb.UploadValues(postURL, "POST", data);
        var responseString = Encoding.Default.GetString(response);
        Response.Write(responseString);
    }
}
```

Code behind Server Side: Default2.aspx

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(IsPostBack)
    {
        Response.Write(Request.Form["jsonString"]); //stuck here
    }      
}
```

Blank result is being posted back to the client (Default.aspx)

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should not it simply be that your code should be executed when the request is not a post-back?
Remember that a PostBack occurs when a control action will be triggered.

Code behind Server Side: Default2.aspx

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(!IsPostBack)
    {
        Response.Write(Request.Form["jsonString"]); //stuck here
    }      
}
```